# Find a formula for the cubic polynomial for any quadratic polynomial q

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

I want to find an exact formula for the cubic polynomial $P_3(x)=x^3+... $ such that $\int_{-1}^1 P_3(x)q(x)dx=0$ for any quadratic polynomial q.

I am thinking that maybe it is of the form $(x-1)^3$, but then I need to integrate it, which would make it become $x^4$, and that is not what I want. Any help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We look for a cubic of the form $P_3(x)=x^3-ax$. Then by symmetry we have $\int_{-1}^1 P_3(x)\cdot 1\,dx=0$ and $\int_{-1}^1 P_3(x)\cdot x^2\,dx=0$.

Now we find $a$ such that $\int_{-1}^1 (x^3-ax)\cdot x\,dx=0$. Compute the integral and set it equal to $0$. We obtain $a=\frac{3}{5}$.

By the linearity of the integral, we conclude that $\int_{-1}^1 \left(x^3-\frac{3}{5}x\right)q(x)\,dx=0$ for all quadratics $q(x)$.

Comment: I am also supposed to find exact formulas for the three roots $x_1, x_2, x_3$ of the equation $P_3(x)=0$. I don't quite understand the question. Since we've already found the formula for $P_3(x)$, why would we need these three roots?

Comment: It is connected with Gaussian quadrature, which may be the next topic. In any case, the polynomial is a simple cubic, and the roots are exceptionally easy to find, since $x=0$ is one of them.

Comment: I think it is the other way around. We are not asked to find the roots, instead we are given three roots $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and we are supposed to use them to find the exact formulas for $P_3(x)$.

Comment: Since we already know that $P_3(x)= x^3-3x/5$ and the three roots are given.. Would the answer be $x_1^3 - 3x_1/5$...

Comment: oh nvm I got it wrong... I think we are given three roots $x_1, x_2 and x_3$ and we are supposed to find $P_3(x)$, which would be $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$

Comment: The roots of our $P_3(x)$ are $0$ and $\pm\sqrt{3/5}$.  If we are given three numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and want a cubic whose roots are these, then yes $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$ does it.

Comment: Yea I think they are two different questions. I messed them up. Thank you!